# How to display DateTimePicker for Excel Ribbon DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010, datetimepicker, ribbon

I have Visual Studio 2010 addin project for Excel 2010 and I need to provide functionality like DateTimePicker in WinForms. But there is no such control for Office Ribbon.

What are my options? Any workaround?

Excel 2010

Comment: Just import the datepicker from winforms

Comment: Import? What does it mean?

Comment: You can design a winform and display it when a button is clicked on the ribbon. It is usually how I deal with more complex user input. I don't know if you can display any winform components directly on the ribbon itself.

Answer (score 1):

The Ribbon UI doesn't provide such control.

You can add a new Windows form to your add-in project and place the DateTime control on the form. Then you can use the following code to display a form with a date time control:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.Show(); // or form1.ShowDialog();
```